# How to remove unattached panel in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, display, 17.04, panel, plasma-5

My desktop is showing up this unattached panel. I've tried to remove it without any success.

I'm running Kubuntu 17.04 with Plasma 5.9.

How can I get rid of this panel?

[image: desktop with unwanted panel]

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to unlock widgets. Right click on any free space on your desktop and choose "Unlock Widgets".
2. Panels are generally removed this way:

   - Click on hamburger button (right side of the panel you want to remove - it should be visible after unlocking widgets)
   - Chose "More Settings..."
   - "Remove Panel"
3. In my humble opinion - this thing on your desktop does not look like a panel - it seems to be some kind of widget. In case I am right and you are unable to remove it using the method above, try this one:

   - Long left click on the widget
   - A toolbox should appear next to the widget. You should find "X" button there.
4. Do not forget to lock widgets (the same way you have unlocked them). Otherwise you can unintentionally move/remove some desktop elements.

[More about panels and widgets on KDE UserBase Wiki](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma#Panels)

Comment: thanks for response. It turned out to be a panel spacer.  It's weird to have panel spacer to be allowed outside panel IMHO. Thanks again.